# Jewishness of person based on religiousness of last four generations of the person’s most recent Jewish ancestors

Tags: sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism, jewishness

[This](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/325154) news article indicates that when the last four generations of a person’s most recent Jewish ancestors were not religiously observant, that person needs to undergo Orthodox conversion le’chumra (as a precautionary measure) to remove any doubts of his Jewishness. It reads,

> However, Rabbi Reich added that Hawila has since undergone an Orthodox conversion le’chumra (as a precautionary measure) to remove any doubts of his Jewishness – a practice employed when the last four generations of a person’s most recent Jewish ancestors were not religiously observant.

I never heard of this 'chumra'. Are there any sources or authorities who codify this practice, or is this a local stricture put in place in just this case?

Comment: Just to clarify there's a big difference between several generations who weren't religious and several generations who practiced a different religion. This guy is from Lebanon and was raised Muslim.

Comment: Sounds fishy to me. Not relevant to your question, which is more of a rant, but that even if this guy is Jewish, he deceived his wife, and should be a mench and divorce her, instead of making a whole drama and sob story on national news.

Comment: @robev were you calling my question a rant? LOL

Comment: This does read as much more of a position statement than a request for information. Please consider editing to make it more of a question about a point of Halacha, with a case from the news as the trigger, and less of a commentary on a situation in the news.